# Posting feed after facebook connect with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, publishing

I'm trying to publish a feed to my users' Facebook wall. I use Facebook Connect for my site. I have generated the link with `getLoginUrl()` with email, offline_access and publish_stream permissions.

My users' click on this link, authenticate with facebook and comes back to my site. When they do, i'm getting their's ID with `getUser()`.

Then i'm trying to publish a post to their walls. I use this:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();

try {
    $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
        'message' => "Mesaj icerigi",
        'link'    => 'http://ithinkdiff.net',
        'picture' => 'http://thinkdiff.net/ithinkdiff.png',
        'name'    => 'iOS Apps & Games',
        'description'=> 'Checkout iOS apps and games from iThinkdiff.net. I found some of them are just awesome!'
        )
    );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

But everytime i try to that, i got an error. Api exception or something. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you give more detail on what the error message is? Specifically, what does print_r($e) output?

Comment: @dsas That would definitely be useful.

Comment: Something like this : FacebookApiException Object ( [result:protected] => Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => (#1) An error occured while creating the share [type] => OAuthException [code] => 1 )

Comment: Anyone help? I'm stuck at here.

Comment: I've never used facebook sdk, but I think that what is happening is that the user is logged in but you do not have permission to share to their feed. Can you check that publish_stream has been granted?